# How to implement oauth2 of Twitter on UWP?

Tags: c#, twitter, oauth, uwp

I want to develop a small twitter application on UWP .

- GET oauth/authenticate
- GET oauth/authorize
- POST oauth/access_token
- POST oauth/request_token
- POST oauth2/invalidate_token
- POST oauth2/token

It is more information. I'm confused. So I want to login to Twitter by ComsumerKey, ComsumerKeySecret, Callback Uri. and get access_token to access data from api.twitter.com.
I think that I've to use POST oauth2/token before(Is it wrong?).

```
 <!-- begin snippet: C# hide: false console: true babel: false -->

 <!-- language: lang-html -->

 public async Task<string> GetAccessTokenBYAuthorizeTwitter()
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            var client = new HttpClient();
            string postData = "grant_type=client_credentials";
            var request = await client.PostAsync(ResourceUrl,new StringContent(postData));
            //request headers
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(ComsumerKeyAndSecret))));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            return await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }

<!-- end snippet -->
```

**Example : I try to login by Vimeo and successful.**

```
public async Task<string> AuthorizeWithVimeo()
    {
        var clientId = "b8e1bff5d5d1f2c90f61017b135960adb42f5fe2";

        var SpotifyUrl = "https://api.vimeo.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(clientId) + "&response_type=code&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString("https://example/callback") + "&state=xyzbc";
        var StartUri = new Uri(SpotifyUrl);
        var EndUri = new Uri("https://example/callback");

        WebAuthenticationResult WebAuthenticationResult = await WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAsync(WebAuthenticationOptions.None, StartUri, EndUri);
        if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.Success)
        {
            var responseData = WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData;

            //await GetSpotifyUserNameAsync(WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseData.ToString());
            return responseData;
        }
        else if (WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus == WebAuthenticationStatus.ErrorHttp)
        {
            return $"HTTP Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : {WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseErrorDetail.ToString()}";
        }
        else
        {
            return $"Error returned by AuthenticateAsync() : {WebAuthenticationResult.ResponseStatus.ToString()}";
        }
    }
```

Comment: What api are you accessing? Client specific or public data there is a different flow for user data

Comment: The first, I need login and get access token before...

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
var client = new HttpClient();

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(
    "Basic",
    Convert.ToBase64String(
        Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
            string.Format("{0}:{1}", Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_key),
                          Uri.EscapeDataString(oauth_consumer_secret)))));

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Host", "api.twitter.com");

var content = new StringContent(postBody);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
HttpResponseMessage response =await client.PostAsync(oauth_url, content);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

using (var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
using (var decompressedStream = new GZipStream(responseStream.Result, CompressionMode.Decompress))
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(decompressedStream))
{
var rawJWt = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
var jwt = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rawJWt);
}
```

[More info](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/729577/API-Talk-to-Twitter-API-Via-Csharp-part)